# Not clear on how exactly pm-hibernate works with server startup

Tags: persistence, shutdown, localserver

I've recently been working with elasticsearch a lot and I've just realized that there's a behaviour that seems totally normal to me, but I have no idea how it works. Basically, I currently have a partitioned drive, running ubuntu and mountain lion under refit. When I shutdown my ubuntu partition I have to restart and reindex data for my local elasticsearch instance.

However, when I close things down using `sudo pm-hibernate` I can move over to my mountain lion partition, then shut down mountain lion, and come back to ubuntu just to see my elasticsearch instance still running with all of my data in it.

What witchcraft is this? How does this work and is there any chance of it breaking? I assume it writes something to my hard drive, but it seems like magic. Anyone have any idea as to how this works?